# Why running second time ansible.windows.win_package isn't working?

Tags: windows, ansible, installation, automation, msi

I have a product that I can install it first, then update it - meaning to add more feature to my base product

I do it by execute the MSI first time, then going to Add \ Remove Programs and when selecting the product, you can click "Change" and the Installation Wizard would shown up again, allowing you to select and install additional feature in the product

I created 2 ansible roles and playbooks for this mission
First role uses ansible.windows.win_package to install the base product (see below example)

```yaml
- name: Install Server.msi primary_appserver
  ansible.windows.win_package:
    path: C:\product.msi
    log_path: C:\InstallProduct.log
    arguments:
     ADDLOCAL=DB,Agent
    state: present
  become: true
  become_method: runas
  vars:
    ansible_become_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
    ansible_become_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
  when: "'primary_appservers' in group_names"
```

Second role uses ansible.windows.win_package again with different ADDLOCAL arguments (the additional features):

```yaml
- name: Install Engine primary_appserver
  ansible.windows.win_package:
    path: C:\product.msi
    log_path: C:\InstallEngine.log
    arguments:
     ADDLOCAL=Engine
    state: present
  become: true
  become_method: runas
  vars:
    ansible_become_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
    ansible_become_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
  when: "'primary_appservers' in group_names"
```

First role is work fine and executes the msi file, The second one - not
If I do those two tasks, with CLI, msiexec /i it's work fine
So, Why it is not working when performing ansible.windows.win_package?

Comment: My guess would be the `state: present`. It is already present, so there is no need to run it again. Is there any file/folder or service you can check for with `creates_path` or `creates_service` that is only created by the second run?

Comment: a new installation log file can be considered?

Comment: Possibly. It's worth a try.

Comment: The additional feature - should add additional directory with its name "Engine" in the product folder. Can we use it in ```create_path``` key?

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of `create_path`, to check if it exists. If not, your task should be executed.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I removed ```state``` and added ```creates_path``` key - It's working like a magic. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is most probably the `state: present` parameter, since the package is already present when the task is run. Instead you can use the `creates_path` or `creates_service` params to check if it is needed to install the package.

Example:

```yaml
- name: Install Engine primary_appserver
  ansible.windows.win_package:
    path: C:\product.msi
    log_path: C:\InstallEngine.log
    arguments:
    ADDLOCAL=Engine
    creates_path: "C:\Path\to\product\folder"
  become: true
  become_method: runas
  vars:
    ansible_become_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
    ansible_become_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
  when: "'primary_appservers' in group_names"
```